# How To Pass Multiple Input Variables from Excel To SQL?? Advice Needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a query that needs to be run on demand by a user to pull data into a workbook. The SQL that pulls this data uses two Variables to pull data into a temporary table: @StartDate and @StopDate but when I go to try to add parameters in the connection's properties, the button is grayed out. I need to have the user be able to input the start and stop dates in Excel to replace the values in the connection definition.

I've tried to Google the solution but they all seem to point to older versions of Excel or SQL.  I am using SQL Server 2016 and Excel 2016.

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date = '2019-08-01' --Date You Want To Start Searching
DECLARE @StopDate Date = '2019-08-19' --Date You want to End on

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp1
SELECT * INTO #Temp1
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
    FROM my_server
    JOIN #Alreadycreatedtable ON ACT.id = #Temp1.Col1 --Join is verified to work--
    WHERE cast(date as DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StopDate 
    ) as #Temp1
```

This pulls fine in SQL. I to have an established connection to the query where the user can put a start date in one cell and end date in another and have those values passed accordingly to @StartDate and @StopDate successfully in order for the query in the connections definition to run with those dates and return the expected query results.  Any advice?

Comment: Well You need to write VBA code in excel, put some button for that function.

[link](https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm) for example

Comment: This was solved by using an active X button with VBA. Was hoping to not have to do it that way.

Comment: I got an idea, meaby put code to event "on Workbook change" cell A1=@startdate, A2=@stopdate, A3=(user input example -> BEGIN), and IF A3 = BEGIN it will trigger code, what do You think ?